# Why can't I cast a generic parameter with type constraint to the constrained type?

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance

I am getting used to using interfaces, generics and develping them using inheritance in a real envrionment whilst trying use and implement this into a new architecture for one of our upcoming projects and I have a question regarding generics which I am confused about.

This is more of a educational question for myself because I can't understand why .NET doesn't allow this.

If I have a generic class which is `(Of T As IA, T2 As A)` then I have the following interfaces and class which implements the base interface

```
Public Interface IA
  Property A As String
End Interface
Public Interface IB
  inherits IA
  Property B As String
End Interface

Public Class GenericClass(Of T As IA, T2 As A)
  'Should be list of IA?
  Public list As New List(Of T)
  Public Sub Add()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Because I have made `T as IA` why in the add method is `Dim foo4 As T = New A()` not legal when

```
Dim foo1 As IA = New A()
Dim foo2 As T
Dim foo3 = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T2)()
Dim x As IA = foo2
Dim y As IA = foo3
list.Add(x)
list.Add(y)
```

All of the above is? This is becoming a learning curve for me with generics etc. but I am just very confused with why I logically can't do this?

EDIT: Sorry forgot `Class A` and error message please see below

```
Public Class A
  Implements IA
  Public Property A As String Implements IA.A
End Class
```

EDIT 2: Error was typed incorrectly

"Value of type class a cannnot be converted to T"

Comment: You have not described your definition of class `A` in the post; I can only assume that `A` does not implement `IA` correctly, or that something else is missing.  Post the definition of `A` so it can be commented on.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted any error message - if it's not legal, the compiler will be telling you the reason.  Post the error message you're seeing.  My best guess (if this is your real code) is that this is a problem of overloaded terms - you have properties and types both called `A`; perhaps something is ambiguous to the compiler.

Comment: @DanPuzey Thanks for the comment - I have posted the code for class A and the error I am getting is that I can't convert A to T.

Comment: And you can make it compile by changing it to `Dim foo4 As T = CType(New A(), T)`, right?  It's just that you're wondering why you need to, right?  I've always wondered that myself.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Even using CType still gives me an error, sorry if the error message I have posted decieved you I read it wrong - updated it now for everybody to see.

Comment: @DanPuzey I suppose the question is why can I successfully create an instance of `T2` through the `activator(of T)` and assign that to `1A`. I can also assign `T` to `1A` but I can't assign a new `A` to `T` when they are constrained to types which can cast for example `Dim i as 1A = new A()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but one problem I notice is that you seem to be assuming that a `List<TypeThatImplementsIA>` is somehow interchangeable with a `List<IA>`.  That is not the case.  Imagine that `A` were a class of flying birds, and `IA` were implemented by creatures that can fly, and someone created a `GenericClass<Airplane, BlueJay)`.  Even though `Airplane` and `BlueJay` are both things that can fly, one would not be able to add a `BlueJay` to a `List<Airplane>`.  The one common situation in the Framework where one can use a `GenericType<DerivedType>` as a `GenericType<BaseType>` is with `IEnumerable<T>`.  The reason for that is that one can't store `T`'s into an `IEnumerable<T>`--one can only read them out.  If one is expecting an `IEnumerable<Animal>` and one is given an `IEnumerable<MaineCoonCat>`, then every time one expects to read an `Animal`, one will read an instance of `MainCoonCat`, which inherits from `Animal` and may thus substitute for it.  This feature of `IEnumerable<T>` is called *covariance*.

There's a limitation to such behavior, though, which stems from the fact that there is a difference between using an interface as a type of storage location (variable, parameter, etc.), versus using it as a constraint.  For every non-nullable value type, there are actually two related types within the Runtime.  One of them is a real value type, which has no concept of inheritance (but can implement interfaces).  The other is a heap-object type which derives from `ValueType` (which in turn derives from `Object`).  Most .net languages will implicitly convert the former type to the latter, and allow code to explicitly convert the latter to the former.  Interface-type storage locations can only hold references to heap objects.  This is significant because it means that while a struct which implements an interface is *convertible* to that interface type, that doesn't mean instance of the struct *is* an instance of that interface type.  Covariance works on the premise that every object returned by e.g. an `IEnumerable<DerivedType>` may be used directly as an instance of `BaseType` *without conversion*.  Such direct substitutability works with inherited class types, and with interfaces that are implemented *by class types*.  It does not work with interfaces implemented by struct types, or with generics that do not have a `class` constraint.  Adding a class constraint to a generic class type parameter will allow that type parameter to participate in covariance, but may preclude the use of structs as the generic type parameter.  Note that unless one has particular reason to expect that an interface will be implemented by structures (as is the case with e.g. `IComparable<T>`, in many cases it's unlikely that an interface would be implemented by a structure and thus a `class`constraint would be harmless).

Comment: I think I followed this through - so infact I want `GenericClass(Of T as IFlyable, T2 FlyingObject)` taking your example, I want to have a `List(of T2)` because you could infact pass anything to `T` that is flyable to this. By constraining `T2` to a `FlyableObject` and having a `List(Of T2)` then `T` would be interchangable?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `T` is not the interface `IA` itself. It is one implementation of it.

Suppose that you have another class that implements `IA`:

```
Public Class B
  Implements IA
  Public Property B_A As String Implements IA.A
  Public Property OtherProperty as Object
End Class
```

Then you create a new instance of `Generic Class` like this:

```
Dim genericObject as new GenericClass(Of B, A)
```

So in this case, `T` now is `B`, and `A` cannot be casted to `B`.

In this case instead, replacing the part of your doubt, a code that would make sense for me:

```
Dim foo4 As IA = New T()
```

**EDIT due to comment**

To be able to instantiate `T`, it is necessary to declare the `New` constraint in the type definition. So the generic class declaration would be:

```
Public Class GenericClass(Of T As {New, IA}, T2 As A)
```

Comment: You can't instansiate a type if you mean to do `Foo4` in the generic class.

Comment: @LukeHennerley I'm not sure if I got what you meant in your comment, but I edited my answer according to my guess.